impossible to recover the old values ​of the elements
in my Laravel application, I have this management rule A Commercial Proposal can contain One or more products and A product can be contained in one or more Commercial Proposal and in the details of the commercial proposal and in the details of the commercial proposal I I created a pop up allowing me to edit and update the product associated with the commercial proposal.
my table allowing me to record a product to associate with a commercial proposal
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('propo_com_produits', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('propo_com_id')->nullable();
        $table->string('produit_id')->nullable();
        $table->string('service_id')->nullable();
        $table->string('description')->nullable();
        $table->string('tva')->nullable();
        $table->string('prix_unitaire_ht')->nullable();
        $table->string('quantite')->nullable();
        $table->string('reduction')->nullable();
        $table->string('prix_revient')->nullable();
        $table->string('total_ht')->nullable();
        $table->string('date_prevue_mis_en_service')->nullable();
        $table->string('date_prevue_fin')->nullable();
        $table->string('user_created_id')->nullable();
        $table->string('user_updated_id')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}

my Commercial Proposal Model :
public function produits ()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Produit::class, 'propo_com_produits',
    'propo_com_id','produit_id',)->withPivot('tva', 'prix_unitaire_ht', 'quantite', 'reduction', 'prix_revient');
}

public function propoCom_produit()
{
    return $this->hasMany(PropoCom_produit::class);
}

my Product model Associated with the commercial proposal :
public function proposition (){
    return $this->belongsTo(PropoCom::class,"propo_com_id");
}

then here is my controller method allowing me to display the details of the commercial proposal and also allowing me to edit the product associated with the commercial proposal:
public function show($id)
{
    $propositions = PropoCom::findOrfail($id);
    $produits = Produit::where('etat_vente', 1)->get();
    $services = Service::where('etat', 1)->get();
    $newproposition = PropoCom::with('produits')->findOrFail($id);
    $newservice = PropoCom::with('services')->findOrFail($id);

    $commerce = $propositions->commerce;

    
    $produitAssocie = PropoCom_produit::where('propo_com_id', $id)->first();

    return view('layouts.commerce.details-propo-brouillon', compact('produitAssocie', 'propositions', 'produits', 'newproposition', 'services', 'newservice', 'commerce'));
}

and in my details view of the commercial proposal :
@foreach($newproposition->propoCom_produit as $produit)
    <tr>
        <th scope="row">{{ $produit->produit_id }}</th>
        <td>{{ $produit->tva }}%</td>
        <td>{{ number_format($produit->prix_unitaire_ht, 0, ',', ' ') }}</td>
        <td>{{ $produit->quantite }}</td>
        <td>{{ number_format($produit->reduction, 0, ',', ' ' )}}</td>
        <td>{{ number_format($produit->prix_revient, 0, ',', ' ') }}</td>
        <td>{{ number_format(($produit->quantite * $produit->prix_unitaire_ht) -  $produit->reduction, 0, ',', ' ')}}</td>
        @if($propositions->etat != 1 && $propositions->etat != 2 && $propositions->etat != 3 && $propositions->etat != 4)
            <td>
            <button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editproduitModal" class="btn btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-pen"></i></button>
                <form onsubmit="return DeleteCinfirm('#')" action="" method="POST">
                    @csrf
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>
                </form>
            </td>
        @endif
    </tr> 
@endforeach

the pop-up allowing me to modify the product associated with the commercial proposal:
<div class="modal fade" id="editproduitModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="editproduitModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="editproduitModalLabel">Modification produit</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
            <form action="{{route('nouvelle.proposition.produit.update', $propositions->id)}}" method="POST">
              @csrf
              {{method_field('PUT')}}
                <div class="col">
                <input type="hidden" name="propo_com_id" value="{{ $propositions->id }}">
                <label for="inputEmail4" class="font-weight-bold">TVA</label>
                    <select id="inputState" class="form-control w-70" name="tva_propo">
                    @foreach (['0', '18'] as $produittva)
                        <option {{ $produittva !== $produitAssocie->tva ? '' : 'selected' }}>{{ $produittva }}</option>
                    @endforeach
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    <label for="inputEmail4" class="font-weight-bold">Prix Unitaire HT</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control w-100" name="prix_unitaire_ht_propo" value="{{ $produitAssocie->prix_unitaire_ht }}">
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    <label for="inputEmail4" class="">Quantité</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control w-100" name="quantite_propo" value="{{ $produitAssocie->quantite }}">
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    <label for="inputEmail4" class="">Réduction</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control w-100" name="reduction_propo" value="{{ $produitAssocie->reduction }}">
                </div>
                <div class="row pt-4 text-center">
                <div class="col">
                    <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary w-50 type="submit">METTRE Â JOUR</button>
                </div>
                </div>                                             
            </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

but in the value fields it only displays the values ​​of the first associated product on all the other products associated with the commercial proposal. Any ideas ?
